# Deletion of particular list item on-click of a button

Tags: javascript

```
function checkBoxStatus(){
var chkbxId=this.id.replace("CB","");
var text=document.getElementById("item"+chkbxId);
if(this.checked){
    text.style.textDecoration="line-through";
}else{
    text.style.textDecoration="none";
}
}function addNewItem(list){
totItems++;
var listItem=document.createElement("ul");
listItem.id="ul"+ totItems;

var listTxtbox=document.getElementById("ToDotxt").value;
if(!listTxtbox || listTxtbox=="" || listTxtbox== " "){
    return false;
}
var checkBox=document.createElement("input");
checkBox.type="checkBox";
checkBox.id="CB"+totItems;
checkBox.onclick=checkBoxStatus;

var span=document.createElement("span");
span.id="item"+totItems;
span.innerText=listTxtbox;
var removeBtn=document.createElement("button");
removeBtn.type="button";
removeBtn.id="remove"+totItems;
removeBtn.innerText="Remove";
removeBtn.onclick=function(){
    var removeID=document.getElementById("TodoList");
    var removeIDsecond=listItem.id;
    this.remove(removeIDsecond);
        }
listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
listItem.appendChild(span);
listItem.appendChild(removeBtn);
list.appendChild(listItem);
}
var totItems=0;
var btnAdd=document.getElementById("addbtn");



btnAdd.onclick=function (){
addNewItem(document.getElementById("TodoList"));
}
```

> I want the remove button to delete the entire list when we click on it. But currently it does not happen and removes the button itself. Please suggest me a way to delete the list when item is striked and remove button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `this.remove(removeIDsecond)`, run `removeIDsecond.remove()`

Comment: I did try using the above method but it shows the message as "Uncaught TypeError:undefined is not a function". Any other ways to sort this out would be of great help. Let me know if more description is required for the question.

Comment: Make a jsFiddle and I can help you out.

Comment: Sorry, I have used JS fiddle but not sure how to customise and send the link to you.

Comment: I did save it using ctrl+S and save it locally as a html file. I did get a url which is local to my machine. Can you please let me know if there is any shortcut key to save other than ctrl+S or are there any hidden buttons.

Comment: Look for a Share/Fork button in the top nav